# How to add ending zero's to the results of a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an field which (default format by oracle im presuming) will remove any ending zero's for example 108.10 will return as 108.1.
What would be the best way to select the field so ending zero are maintained and will not add additional zero's to for example 108.11.

EDIT: Unfortunately the question has been closed and I cannot answer, here is the solution I have found. this works with values with varying character lengths I have tested within the following range 0.10 - 99999.10 the below will always return 2 decimal points.

```
SELECT LTRIM(TO_CHAR(COL1,'9999.990')) FROM table1;
```

Comment: If you are calling Oracle from somewhere (e.g. Java, C#), then just handle this presentation issue there.

Comment: If it is just for report purposes convert your data into a varchar using `TO_CHAR` with the desired format mask. (But work internally (joins etc.) with the original data!)

Comment: If you have a fixed number of decimal places then use `TO_CHAR( value, '99999.00' )` to display those two decimal places. If you have a variable number of decimal places then you either need to store the number of decimal places as a separate field or store the entire number as a string.

Comment: Regarding your EDIT: The solution you wrote will show THREE decimal places; in your question you asked for two. Separately: instead of LTRIM, use the correct format model: instead of `'999.990'`, which will add a space to the left (placeholder for the sign), the model should be `'fm999.990'`. The **`fm`** modifier means "if the number is negative then show the minus sign, but otherwise do NOT include a leading space as placeholder for the sign."

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to the appropriate `decimal`/`numeric`/`number` type.  To be explicit, you might do:

```
select cast(col as decimal(10, 2))
```

Comment: How would this casting to `decimal(10,2)` affect what is being **displayed** in the output? `select cast(108.10 as decimal(10,2))` still outputs `108.1`, not `108.10`.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Any tool that displays data should be recognizing the underlying data type.  It would be a foolish tool that didn't do that.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. The standard Oracle tools, like SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer, behave exactly as I said in my Comment. They may be foolish, but surely not for the reason you give. By the way, that's something you can test yourself - the test is really the one-liner I wrote for you. Please let us know in which tool you tested and you saw the behavior you claim.